# Python fastest way of limiting list occurences

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm wondering why `list.count()` which is in O(n) is nearly as fast as my custom method with 2 if and 2 assignations.

The basic method should be in `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of input elements and `m` the length of output elements.
My method should be in `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the input elements.

Any idea would be appreciated.

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from typing import List

def run_test_timings(func, n_repeat, *args):
    start = timer()
    res = [func(*args) for _ in range(n_repeat)]
    end = timer()
    return end - start, res

def method_custom(elements: List[int], exclude_len: int = 2):
    elements_out = list()

    # 0(len(elements) * ~1)
    prev_val, prev_val_counter = None, 0
    for element in elements:
        prev_val_counter = prev_val_counter + 1 if element == prev_val else 0

        if prev_val_counter < exclude_len:
            elements_out.append(element)

        prev_val = element

    return elements_out


def method_count(elements: List[int], exclude_len: int = 2):
    elements_out = []

    # O(len(elements) * len(elements_out))
    for values in elements:
        if elements_out.count(values) < exclude_len:
            elements_out.append(values)

    return elements_out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N_TESTS = 1_000_000
    INPUT_ELEMENTS = sorted([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8])
    print(f'n_tests : {N_TESTS}')

    print('method_count timer : ', end='')
    timer_1, res_1 = run_test_timings(method_count, N_TESTS, INPUT_ELEMENTS)
    print(timer_1, res_1[0])

    print('method_custom timer : ', end='')
    timer_2, res_2 = run_test_timings(method_custom, N_TESTS, INPUT_ELEMENTS)
    print(timer_2, res_2[0])
```

Output :

```
n_tests : 1000000
method_count timer : 1.665171445987653 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
method_custom timer : 1.5837802449823357 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
```

Comment: Have you tried with different lengths to check your `O` assumptions? Note that `O` is the *asymptotic* complexity, not absolute timings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the number of elements makes it very obvious than there is HUGE gains as expected.

Here is the full code.

```py
import random
from typing import List
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def run_test_timings(func, n_repeat, *args):
    start = timer()
    res = [func(*args) for _ in range(n_repeat)]
    end = timer()
    return end - start, res


def method_custom(elements: List[int], exclude_len: int = 2):
    elements_out = list()

    # 0(len(elements) * ~1)
    prev_val, prev_val_counter = None, 0
    for element in elements:
        prev_val_counter = prev_val_counter + 1 if element == prev_val else 0

        if prev_val_counter < exclude_len:
            elements_out.append(element)

        prev_val = element

    return elements_out


def method_count(elements: List[int], exclude_len: int = 2):
    elements_out = []

    # O(len(elements) * len(elements_out))
    for values in elements:
        if elements_out.count(values) < exclude_len:
            elements_out.append(values)

    return elements_out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N_TESTS = 1_000
    N_ELEMENTS = 1_000
    print(f'N_TESTS    : {N_TESTS}')
    print(f'N_ELEMENTS : {N_ELEMENTS}')

    INPUT_ELEMENTS = sorted([random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(N_ELEMENTS)])

    print('method_count timer : ', end='')
    timer_1, res_1 = run_test_timings(method_count, N_TESTS, INPUT_ELEMENTS)
    print(timer_1)  # , res_1[0])

    print('method_custom timer : ', end='')
    timer_2, res_2 = run_test_timings(method_custom, N_TESTS, INPUT_ELEMENTS)
    print(timer_2)  # , res_2[0])
```